# Booting for BeagleBone Black

Tags: embedded-linux

I begin embedded Linux with BeagleBone Black. I use crosstool-NG to build U-boot. Result is file MLO and u-boot.img, which was wrtite into SD cards.
Then, I insert SD cards into BeagleBone Black to test.
I follow this decription https://elinux.org/Building_for_BeagleBone#U-Boot

But, it don't show #U-boot.
Note that i just test uboot, not kernel image and root file system. And a uboot image is available on the onboard eMMC.
How do I fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: *"I use crosstool-NG to build U-boot"* -- No, you did not.  More likely you used  crosstool-NG to build a toolchain, and then used that toolchain to build U-Boot.  Did you build the toolchain correctly? Did you build U-Boot correctly?  Maybe you should reduce the number of unknowns by using a prebuilt toolchain?  BTW your title and selection of tag desn't match your problem/question.  And somebody is going to flag this as "not a programming" question.

Comment: Thank you!
I'm also try with a prebuilt toolchain, but result is not change.

Comment: Hi Sawdust, I sloved my problem. Using tool "picocom" will done, do not use "minicom".

Comment: Hi Nguyen, i followed similar steps. However, i am not able to find /dev/ttyUSB for my BeagleBone Black. Were you able to find the /dev/ttyUSB of your BBB?